# Nächster oder nächste?

Tags: adjective, declension, time

My books says:

1. Time expressions go in the accusative.
2. Feminine adjectives without article take the declension *-e*  in the accusative.

Then what is going on with **"nächster Woche"** in the following sentence?

> Ich möchte für Dienstagabend nächster Woche einen Tisch reservieren.

*Nächster Woche* is a time expression, *Woche* is feminine and *nächster* is an adjective.  Following the rules it should be *nächste Woche*.

How do I make sense of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> für Dienstagabend nächster Woche

"nächster Woche" is a genitive within this whole accusative object. Therefore the different ending. E.g. as direct accusative object "für nächste Woche" would be correct, as you expected.

Comment: Could you elaborate please?. I am a beginner.  How do I recognize it is genitive? Genitive is used for posession, right, (which i don't see here)?  The whole expression" für Dienstagabend nächster" since to be a single answer for the question  Wan?  Dienstagabend nächster Woche

Comment: @juan carlos vega oliver - Possession is just one use case. Here you give a closer specification: it's not just any Tuesday evening but the Tuesday evening of next week. You see, in English it's a genitive structure, too: next week's Tuesday.

Comment: Then I should be able to write using "von" and the dative  instead of the genitive:   für Dienstagabend  von nächster (in dative) Woche  . Would that be correct?

Comment: @juan carlos vega oliver - That's talk you may actually hear in Germany but grammar books (-> tests) will probably not let you get away with it. So, officially it's wrong and sounds a bit weird (unnecessary complicated), too.